# Sampling a distribution until it falls in a given set of values

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I came up with a family of distributions and I wondered **if it has been previously studied and whether there is a name for it**. Let me define it and find its cumulative distribution function (cdf) and probability density function (pdf) to provide some context.

## Definition

Let $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed **normal** random variables. Let $I = [a, b]$ be an nontrivial interval. We define a sample $y$ of the random variable $Y$ in the following manner:

1. We take a sample $x_0$ from $X_0$. If $x_0 \in I$, then $y = x_0$.
2. Otherwise, we take a sample $x_1$ from $X_1$. If $x_1 \in I$, then $y = x_1$.
3. Otherwise, we take a sample $x_2$ from $X_2$. If $x_2 \in I$, then $y = x_2$.
4. etc.

In layman's terms, we define $Y$ by sampling the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ until we obtain a value which falls in the interval $I$.

## Cumulative distribution function and probability density function

For $y \le a$, the cpf of $Y$ is trivially given by $p(Y \le y) = 0$, whereas for $b \le y$ we have $p(Y \le y) = 1$. For convenience, let us define $q = p(X_0 \not\in I)$ and consider the case $y \in I$.
\begin{equation}
    p(Y \le y) = p(a \le X_0 \le y) + p(X_0 \not\in I)p(a \le X_1 \le y) + p(X_0 \not\in I)p(X_1 \not\in I)p(a \le X_2 \le y) + \cdots
\end{equation}

This can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
    p(Y \le y) = \sum_{n \ge 0}q^np(a \le X_0 \le y) = \frac{1}{1 - q}p(a \le X_0 \le y).
\end{equation}

Thus, the pdf is given by
\begin{equation}
    f_{Y}(y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}p(Y \le y) = \frac{1}{1 - q}f_{X_0}(y)\chi_{I}(y),
\end{equation}

where $\chi_{I}(y)$ denotes the indicator function corresponding to the interval $I$, and $f_{X_0}(x)$ is the pdf of $X_0$.

## Thoughts

In this case the result seems rather trivial, both the cdf and pdf just get scaled, which makes sense considering how we have defined $Y$. Part of my interest lies too on whether this has been proposed for **other random variables** (*not normal* and maybe discrete) and **other sets** ($I$ not necessarily an interval).

Comment: In effect you have a [truncated distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) and a form of [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). It can be generalised to more general $I$ at least when $\mathbb P(X \in I)>0$

Comment: What you call a *characteristic function* would usually  in probability and statistics be called an *[indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)* while a [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) would typically mean something else

Comment: Ah truncated is the keyword that I needed. Indeed, there is a Wikipedia article dedicated entirely to the [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution). Thank you!